# How to get asp.net created cookies in Java servlet?

Tags: java, asp.net, servlets

How to get ASP.NET created cookies in a Java servlet?

This is My Cookie In ASP.NET

```
emid=11&eud=11&euid=33zU4Yq/p3k=&euseremail=F/zVoXtd4NoAd7yj6Z47gxFVaMCMYha/La6IzlC+xQo=&euserid=33zU4Yq/p3k=&emdn=testing
```

But when I try To Call it in Servlet it only prints: **emid** [only print the starting string before first equal to (=) sign]

I'm using the following code in Servlet to print cookies..

```
        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = null;
        cookies = request.getCookies();
        if( cookies != null ){
            out.println("<h2> Found Cookies Name and Value</h2>");
            for (int I = 0; I < cookies.length; I++){
               cookie = cookies[I];
               out.print("Name : " + cookie.getName( ) + ",  ");
               out.print("Value: " + cookie.getValue( )+" \n");
            }
         }else{
             out.println(
               "<h2>No cookies founds</h2>");
         }
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Just wondering, what's the functional requirement? Sending a query string like data as a cookie instead of as a query string is rather strange. Are you sure that you aren't mixing some basic concepts?

Answer (score 1):

The equals character is a reserved character in a cookie value. The specification compliant way of fixing this is to quote the  cookie value by surrounding it with double quotes. However, some browsers don't handle this very well. If you are using Tomcat you can set the system property `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true` to allow equals in cookie values.

Comment: do i add this value specifically for my website or this will for all sites under that apache system?

Comment: It applies to the entire Tomcat instance so all web applications deployed on that instance will be affected.

Comment: how i do make it only for my site or for particular servlet